# Is it possible to show bitmap in a parallelogram shape?

Tags: android, android-canvas, image-manipulation

Normally, when you draw a bitmap to the canvas, it is rectangular. Is it possible to make it appear as a parallelogram instead?

Comment: What kind of 3d effect are you talking about? A stereoscopic effect will be visible if it's already contained in the bitmap but you will need 3d-glasses. You will not be able to draw a normal image in 3d.

Comment: ya sorry...  bit modification in my question,..i wan a show a bitmap in parallelogram with out using Path , i.e with out hiding the any part of the bitmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `canvas.skew(20, 0)`.  That skews the drawing matrix in x, but you can obviously do y as well, depending on what you need.